# Change background of li element on li:hover with a css background image

Tags: hover, html-lists

I have a bunch of li elements with background images working fine on the normal state. The minute i add the hover class to any one of the images they move on the y aaxis about 25px or so down the page when you mouse over that specific image. I tried setting "background-position:0 0" in the hover states along with margin etc and neither worked. I also tried changing the elements so it used "a:hover" instead and that didn't work either.

What am i doing wrong? How can i get this so the hover position is in the same place?

**My Code:**

```
<div class="contentBottom">
<ul class="featuredIn">
<li class="featured1"><a href="mylink1.html"></a></li>
<li class="featured2"><a href="mylink2.html"></a></li>
<li class="featured3"><a href="mylink3.html"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

li.featured1 {
    background: url(featured_in/1.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width: 83px;    
    height: 43px;
}

li.featured1:hover {
    background: url(featured_in/1_hover.png) no-repeat;
}

li.featured2 {
    background: url(featured_in/2.png) no-repeat;
    width: 203px;   
    height: 42px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

li.featured2:hover {
    background: url(featured_in/2_hover.png) no-repeat;
}

li.featured3 {
    background: url(featured_in/3.png) no-repeat;
    width: 143px;
    height: 21px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

li.featured3:hover {
    background: url(featured_in/3_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an online example (on your server, or a jsfiddle or something) where the problem can be reproduced, including your actual background images (otherwise we see nothing). And also the info, which browsers this problem concerns.

Comment: found the solution. It was simply that i had a hover image that was bigger that the normal state.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a image to the background element like so.

```
background-image: url(featured_in/3.png) no-repeat;
```

You could also try adding '' to the url element like so.

```
background: url('featured_in/3.png') no-repeat;
```

I hope this helps:)